# UITextField max inputview height

Tags: ios, uitextfield, height, first-responder, inputview

In my app I'm using an `UIView` as my inputView for a `UITextField`. The `UIView` height is 252.
The problem is that when the textfield becomes first responder only the top 216 pixels are shown. 
Is there a max height for `UITextField` inputView?

Comment: Other pixels are hidden by keyboard? Or view becomes trimmed  on screen?

Comment: Actually it is a view containing a pickerview (at bottom) and an image view with 36 pixels height at the top. the 36 imageview pixels are shown + the top 180 pxl from the pickerview  = 216 pxl are shown.

Comment: And other bottom pixels are just trimmed all the time?

Answer (score -3):

Yes maximum and minimum => fixed height for a textfield is 31, you can see it in the xib itself - drag and drop